# How to find the index of of value in array in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table and some sample data as well. I want to get the index of each value in array in separate column.

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR (100),
   phones TEXT []
);
```

Sample data.

```
INSERT INTO contacts (name, phones)
VALUES
  (
      'John Doe',
      '{"(408)-589-5846","(408)-589-5555"}'
   ),   
   (
      'Lily Bush',
      '{"(408)-589-5841"}'
   ),
   (
      'William Gate',
      '{"(408)-589-5842","(408)-589-58423"}'
   );
```

Now I run this query to unnest the data into rows which is something like this.

```
select name, unnest(phones) from contacts
```

It gives me the data correctly but I want the number of index for the phone numbers in another column which will help me identify which phone number is at which index.
I came to know with `array_position()` function but it's not working as expected and throwing some error, maybe I'm not putting in right way. I am new to postgresql so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unnest() in the FROM clause and you get the the index using the option `with ordinality`

```
select c.name, 
       p.phone,
       p.idx
from contacts c
  cross join lateral unnest(phones) with ordinality as p(phone, idx)
order by c.id, p.idx;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7cdae6fa8d70188efb40958841147991)

The above would not return rows from the contacts table that have an empty phones array, if you need that you need to use a LEFT JOIN

```
select c.name, 
       p.phone,
       p.idx
from contacts c
  left join lateral unnest(phones) with ordinality as p(phone, idx) on true
order by c.id, p.idx;
```